# nodejs unit test stubs with neo4j

Tags: node.js, neo4j, sails.js, waterline

Anyone know of a way to spin up a neo4j instance for testing?

We're using Nodejs + Neo4j, with minimal unit tests which I'd like to change.

[NosqlUnit](https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit) looks promising but its dependant on JUint to run.

The Neo4j class `com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.neo4j.InMemoryNeo4j` sounds fantastic. But I cant find any info on Google or Stackoverflow. Could this potentially be invoked by Java or Scala while running my tests in Nodejs?

Any help hints tips or tricks welcomed.

---

**Update**

I think using nodejs & [sails-memory](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-memory) is a good option. As the main concern is testing the application layer. Using the waterline orm will allow me to swap databases for testing purposes.